# How to force 2+2=5

Tags: evaluation, downvalues, upvalues

I was looking at [this question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/28786/write-a-program-that-makes-2-2-5/28869#28869) (writing a program such that 2 + 2 = 5) and tried to write something in Mathematica, but I couldn't get something to work without completely replacing `Plus`. Neither of these worked:

```
Unprotect[Plus]
Plus[2, 2] := 5
Unprotect[Integer]
2 + 2 ^= 5
```

[This book](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=8S7QA-WzsJ0C&pg=PA223&lpg=PA223&dq=%22Unprotect%5BPlus%5D%22&source=bl&ots=9jgc9pJ1Th&sig=-TyUgIHWRMDWT4roKg2BMty8yqI&hl=en&sa=X&ei=qVmMU4_dL8TYOquXgYAL&ved=0CF4Q6AEwBw#v=onepage&q=%22Unprotect%5BPlus%5D%22&f=false) suggests that `Plus` and `Times` have special rules. Is this really impossible to do?

Comment: Something like `Block[{Plus = Times}, 2 + 3]`

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom that's what I meant with "completely replacing `Plus`"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Another solution for this weird exercise is to make a combination from using `$Pre` and defining a new `plus` function. You use `$Pre` to replace every occurrence of `Plus` by your own definition which only act special at the input `plus[2,2]` and calls the normal `Plus` otherwise:

```
SetAttributes[plus, Attributes[Plus]];
Unprotect[plus];
plus[2, 2] = 5;
plus[args___] := Plus[args];
$Pre = Function[Null,
   ReleaseHold[Hold[#] /. Plus :> plus], HoldAllComplete];
```

Now, the obvious input `2+2` works as well as e.g. `4/2 + (6 - 4)` but I wouldn't bet that this works in all circumstances.

Comment: A simpler use of \$Pre would be just \$Pre = (# /. Plus[2, 2] :> 5) &

Comment: Presumably, because Function has the attribute HoldAll.

Comment: @BobHanlon That solution won't work unless you use `HoldPattern` *and* set the attribute `HoldAll` on the function, as in `$Pre = Function[x, Unevaluated[x] /. HoldPattern@Plus[2, 2] :> 5, 
  HoldAll]`.  Otherwise it will only replace the input `4` with `5`, not replace `2+2` with `5`. Consider the input `3(2+2)` or the input `4`.

Comment: Disregard my original comment.

Answer (score 8):

How about this ;-)

```
\!\(\*InterpretationBox[2,3]\)+2
```

Comment: This one made me laugh. Very creative!

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
mp[2, 2] = 5
Block[{Plus = mp}, 2 + 2]
(*5*)
```

Now of course the interesting question is why `Unprotect` does not work as expected? I have not yet figured it out. Nothing special is seen in the Attributes. Actually doing

```
Unprotect[Plus]
Plus[2, 2] = 5
??Plus
```

shows the new rule.

Comment: `Plus` is handled specially and is subject to all sorts of evaluation shortcuts, at least for numeric arguments. In this case it would probably be better to think of the definitions as showing you how `Plus` behaves, rather than that the behavior actually comes from those definitions as in the usual case.