# Unset Built-in Functions (Times, Dot, etc)

Tags: functions

Yes, I know, I should never *actually* do this in a package or something. But I'm curious - how could I undefine Times or Plus or the like? I tried Unprotect and Clear, but that didn't seem to work.

Comment: Related: [(19126)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19126), [(89832)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/89832)

Comment: Also: [48929](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/48929/5478)

Comment: Hm. Interesting, but that doesn't answer the question for Dot, which as far as I know isn't defined this way and still refuses to be redefined.

Comment: Why? `Unprotect[Dot];
Dot[x_, y_] := x^2 + y^2;
Protect[Dot];` then `Dot[a, b]` yields $a^2+b^2$, and `Dot[2, 5]` gives $29$. Although this trick indeed doesn't work for `Plus`.